# MBP Mid 2010 won't hibernate, runs battery dead

Tags: sleep-wake, hibernate

I have a mid 2010 running High Sierra and it won't hibernate (or safe sleep? I'm confused on the right term).

When I close the lid it goes into standby as you would expect, but it never goes into sleep or hibernate. As a result the RAM runs the battery completely dead in a day or so, like so dead that sometimes I have to reset my system clock. The only way to prevent this is to actually shut the computer down before closing the lid. When I run `pmset -G` in terminal, this is what I get, but I don't know what it means, specifically the part about "(sleep prevented by storedownloadd, UserEventAgent)".

```
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by storedownloadd, UserEventAgent)
 hibernatemode        3 
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         15
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

I'd like to figure this out so that I don't have to fully shut down the computer every time it is going to be off for more than a day, when I forget it completely drains the battery and it has already led to the early death of one battery. I'd like for it to not destroy my new battery as well. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you here the cd/dvd drive ? (I had this problem and had to disconnect it to be able to suspend my lid-2010 MacBook Pro.

Comment: If you've reset the Power Management https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295 and it still doesn't work, then it's likely there's a hardware fault.